# React class component methods: is my code imperative?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and as well to the terms of functional, imperative, declarative. And I get to know that pure function is easy to test. I am self taught to program with Javascript. So far, it is working but my goal is to learn to write clean and maintainable code.
my question is the method `addProductToSaleList` below is bad and untestable because it is imperative? and how can I do it differently.

```
class SaleComponent extends React.Component {

    addProductToSaleList = (values, dispatch, props) => {
        //filter product from productList 
        const productFound = props.productList.filter(product => {
            if (values.productCode === product.code.toString()) {
                return product
            }
            return undefined
        })[0]

        if (productFound) {

            // filter sale list to check if there is already product in the list.
            const detailFound = props.saleItem.details.filter(detail => {
                if (productFound.name === detail.product) {
                    return detail
                }
                return undefined
            })[0]

            // if it is exist just increment the qty
            if (detailFound) { 
                const { sub_total, ...rest } = detailFound
                props.dispatcher('UPDATE_SALEDETAIL_ASYNC', {
                    ...rest,
                    qty: parseInt(detailFound.qty, 10) + 1
                })

            // if it is not exist add new one
            } else { 
                props.dispatcher('ADD_SALEDETAIL_ASYNC', {
                    product: productFound.id,
                    price: productFound.price,
                    qty: 1
                })
            }
        } else {

            alert('The product code you add is not exist in product list');
        }
    }
    render() {
        // Render saleList
    }
}
```

Comment: `return undefined` -> `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive this question should go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I will give it a shot. Part of the code can be improved

```
const productFound = props.productList.filter(product => {
        if (values.productCode === product.code.toString()) {
            return product
        }
        return undefined
    })[0]
```

First, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) function receives a callback and for each item that callback will be executed. If the callback returns a value interpreted as true, it will return the item in the new array the function will build. Otherwise, it will skip that item. Assuming you're trying to find one item in the code, you could use the function [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) which will return you that element directly (no need for `[0]`), or undefined if that item is not found. So your code could be rewrite to

```
const productFound = props.productList.find(product => values.productCode === product.code.toString());
```

**Note: No IE support.**

Then, if the value was not found, you could just alert and do an [early return](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement). (You might also want to handle errors differently, with a better format than plain alert).

The code would look like

```
if (!productFound) {
    alert('The product code you add is not exist in product list');
    return;
}
// rest of the function
```

in order to find details, you can use `find` method as well

```
const detailFound = props.saleItem.details.find(detail => productFound.name === detail.product);
```

and then just call the rest of the code

```
// if it is exist just increment the qty
    if (detailFound) { 
        const { sub_total, ...rest } = detailFound
        props.dispatcher('UPDATE_SALEDETAIL_ASYNC', {
            ...rest,
            qty: parseInt(detailFound.qty, 10) + 1
        })

    // if it is not exist add new one
    } else { 
        props.dispatcher('ADD_SALEDETAIL_ASYNC', {
            product: productFound.id,
            price: productFound.price,
            qty: 1
        })
    }
```

Another improvement:

You're receiving a dispatch function as a parameter, but you're not using it. So you could remove it from function's declaration

```
(values, props) => { ... }
```

And you could split the last part into two different functions, something like

```
const getAction = details => `${detailFound ? 'UPDATE' : 'ADD'}_SALEDETAIL_ASYNC`;

const getObject = (details, productFound) => {
        if (!details) {
            return {
                product: productFound.id,
                price: productFound.price,
                qty: 1
            };
        }
        const { sub_total, ...rest } = detailFound;
        return  {
            ...rest,
            qty: parseInt(detailFound.qty, 10) + 1
        };
    }
```

and then just call

```
props.dispatcher(getAction(details), getObject(details, productFound));
```

The end result would look like

```
addProductToSaleList = (values, props) => {
    //filter product from productList 
    const productFound = props.productList.find(product => values.productCode === product.code.toString());

    if (!productFound) {
        alert('The product code you add is not exist in product list');
        return;
    }

    // filter sale list to check if there is already product in the list.
    const detailFound = props.saleItem.details.find(detail => productFound.name === detail.product);

    const getAction = details => `${details ? 'UPDATE' : 'ADD'}_SALEDETAIL_ASYNC`;

    const getObject = (details, productFound) => {
        if (!details) {
            return {
                product: productFound.id,
                price: productFound.price,
                qty: 1
            };
        }
        const { sub_total, ...rest } = details;
        return  {
            ...rest,
            qty: parseInt(details.qty, 10) + 1
        };
    }

    props.dispatcher(getAction(details), getObject(details, productFound));
}
```

> my question is the method addProductToSaleList below is bad and
>   untestable because it is imperative

Well your code is testable, there are no external dependencies. So you could pass mocked values and props and add unit tests to that. That means, passing a fake `values` and `props` (they are just plain js object) and make assertions over that.

For instance:

You could mock `dispatcher` function and given the fake values in productList and `saleItem.details` you could see if `dispatcher` is called with the proper values. You should test different combinations of that

Mock `alert` function (Again, I would use another UI approach) and verify it is called, and that no other code is called (asserting that your fake `dispatcher` is not called). Something like this:

```
   let actionToAssert;
    let objectToAssert;
    let values = { productCode: 'somecode' };
    let props = { 
      productList: // your item listm with id and price, name, etc,
      saleItem: {
         details: // your details array here
      }
      dispatcher: (action, newObject) => {
         actionToAssert = action;
         objectToAssert = newObject;
      }   
    }
    addProductToSaleList(values, props);    // make here assertions over actionToAssert and objectToAssert
```

Comment: Thank you very much! very clean. I learn a lot from this. can I move it to code review? I did not know about it.